# How to Install IIS through Code

Tags: iis, installation, redistributable

In My application i have to install IIS automatically when my application install in User machine (Vista / XP) with out using OS Cd's.

Can any one please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is not a re-distributable component. This means that you can't bundle it with your application. The user **must** have their OS media and install it from there.

You can do a scripted silent install. Check out this [scripted installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4030adbb-5982-4cbc-af44-7f1e6834ceaa.mspx?mfr=true) for a  basic description of what to do. You will also need to create an [answer file](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4030adbb-5982-4cbc-af44-7f1e6834ceaa.mspx?mfr=true) to manage the settings for the unattended installation.

The procedure is different for [IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/133/using-unattend-setup-to-install-iis-7/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application is ASP.NET, you probably should bundle it with [UltiDev Web Server Pro (UWS)](http://ultidev.com/products/UWS/) - it's a free, redistributable web server that can be added to your installer project [as a prerequisite](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postsm2832_UWS-Screenshots.aspx#post2832).